# Configuring HUAWEI E3531 Permission Denied in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, permissions, usb-modem

I tried to follow this method (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217416) with no luck. When I put my modem, it always show Mass Storage Mode, here's my `lsusb` result:

```
denny@GIGABYTE-PC ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 12d1:15ca Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E3131 3G/UMTS/HSPA+ Modem (Mass Storage Mode)
```

Note here that vid:pid value should be 12d1:1506 then I try `modprobe -v option` and followed by

```
sudo echo "12d1 1506" >/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
bash: /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id: Permission denied
```

No matter what vid:pid that I supplied, system always spouts permission denied.
So what's wrong ? and is there easier way to use my USB modem with Ubuntu ?

Comment: use `echo "thing" | sudo tee file` instead of `>`, or do `sudo -i` then repeat the command - redirection will not work with `sudo`

Comment: oh no wait... you're trying to write to `/sys` which isn't a real file system... that "file" might not be writable at all

Comment: if you can write to it and it works, you can use `sysfsutils` to make the change permanent...

Comment: after a long research into this: No, I can't write anything into it, sometimes I can but it will be immediately rewritten by Ubuntu. In the end, I just want to surf the net with my USB modem, so I found another way to do that (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF8xI_DM9NY). I just curious why soooo many people suggested this method, it doesn't work for me and I have tested it in my PC, laptop, and my friend's PC, none worked